# Does "Ein Ye'ush" apply to everything or just spiritual related things?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, chasidut-hasidism

I have recently heard about a concept called "[Ein Ye'ush Baolam Clal](https://www.breslev.co.il/articles/spirituality_and_faith/spiritual_growth/there_is_no_such_thing_as_despair.aspx?id=1917&language=english)" ("[אין יאוש בעולם כלל](https://www.breslev.co.il/articles/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A9_%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%9C_%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8/%D7%97%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D.aspx?id=6692&language=hebrew)") which translates as "There is never a time of despair".

I was wondering if this is referring to all things, or just things related to Torah and mitzvoth. And where is the source for it?

Comment: Hi Simon. I've never heard of that before. Where did you hear of it?

Comment: There is yeush for Aveda and gezel

Comment: @SimonL JSYK if you put @ and the user’s name (as I’ve done at the beginning of this comment) you’ll ping the person you’re responding to, so they’ll know that you’re responding to them.

Comment: @DonielF thank you. im new to this

Answer (score -2):

It most definitely applies even to mundane things. (*Likutei Moharan Tinyana, Torah* 78)

Comment: Are you referring to https://www.sefaria.org/Likutei_Moharan%2C_Part_II.78.7.3? This isn’t what he says at all. What he says is that one should never despair of repenting. He doesn’t say anything about mundane things there.